# Как убрать пробелы при выводе?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Написал код для парсинга информации о пользователях ВК по определенному промежутку `id`. Подскажите, как убрать пробелы между `@id` и числом `id`

КОД:

```
import requests #импортируем библиотеку для работы с API ВК
us_id=range(15155637,15155677,1) #ввели последовательность с шагом 1
for i in us_id: #запускаем цикл для i в границах переменной us_id
    r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get',params={'user_ids':i,'fields':'followers_count'})#обращение к API
    response=r.json() #присваиваем переменной response значение r.json()
    d=response['response'][0]['uid'] #присваиваем переменной d значение id аккаунта из словаря
    f=response['response'][0]['first_name'] #присваиваем переменной f значение имя пользователя из словаря
    print('@id',d,'(',f,')') # Выводим данные в текстовом формате, в человеческом восприятии
```

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ:

```
@id 15155637 ( Ямиль )
@id 15155638 ( Елена )
```

НЕОБХОДИМЫЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ:

```
@id15155637 ( Ямиль )
@id15155638 ( Елена )
```

Comment: Бессмысленное комментирование каждой строки вредно для здоровья, не делайте так

Comment: А, это не вы делали. @user246325 зачем вы комментируете каждую строку?

Comment: Пока комментирую постоянно чтобы закрепилось в памяти. Потом буду выборочно только комментировать.

Comment: Кстати, этот код в будущем сломается, потому что не указана версия API https://vk.com/dev/version_update

Comment: Да код временный, главное чтобы спарсить всех пользователей ВК, с последующей их записью в файл, сортировать по признакам, а потом рассылать уведомления через 100 публичных страниц, так сказать персональная реклама с оповещением 25000 ежедневно. Хотя можно и больше!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Замена в строках `d = response['response'][0]['uid'].replace(' ', '')` но там у вас просто значение, тогда просто форматирует строку печати:
`print('@id{0} ({1})'.format(d, f))`

Comment: Для `Python-3.6` `f'@id{d} ({f})'`

Comment: Так даже красивее получается!) То что надо!

Answer (score 4):

изучите форматирование строк с помощью метода [format](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html)

```
us_id = 15155637, 15155638
r = iter([{'uid': 1, 'first_name': 'Ямиль', 'other': 0},
          {'uid': 2, 'first_name': 'Елена', 'other': 0}])

s = '@id{i} {uid} ( {first_name} )'
for i in us_id:
    response = next(r)
    print(s.format(i=i, **response))

>>> @id15155637 1 ( Ямиль )
>>> @id15155638 2 ( Елена )
```

Answer (score 2):

Дополню этим вариантом:

```
print('@id%d %s' % (d, f))
```

Comment: Ну это `Python-2.x` стиль. Лучше просто в комментарий)